# Xcode Swift Package manager

Tags: swift, xcode

The first day learning Swift and trying to install a package but I keep getting a swift package manager Authentication failed because no credentials were provided error.

I am trying to pull the Apollo Graphql package using ssh.

`git@github.com:apollographql/apollo-ios.git`

In my preferences, I have hooked up my Git hub account.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: change auth method to SSH from HTTPS in Github account preferences on Xcode.

Comment: Just done that, and now it says to create a token for the login. Create token and still get error Authentication failed because no credentials were provided error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393161/1780632 try this

Comment: Still getting Authentication failed because no credentials were provided error.

Comment: Try the https url instead: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios